# Absolute convergence of $ \sum \ln\left(1+\frac{ (-1)^n }{n}\right) $?

Tags: calculus

If we take:

$$ \sum_2 ^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{ (-1)^n }{n}\right) $$

I know it converges, because this is actually a kind of telescopic series .

But, does it absolutely converge? I have no idea how to prove it

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you start at n=1, the fist term is log(0). Could that impact ?

Comment: Write it explicitly by splitting in odd and even values of $\large n$. You'll see the general term $\large\sim{1 \over n^{2}}$ when $\large n \gg 1$.

Comment: Numerically, $\large \approx 4.67\times 10^{-3}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin. I totally agree if the summation goes from $n=2$ to infinity.

Comment: Could you please indicate in the post the bounds for summation ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm sorry. $\large n \geq 2$. Thanks.

Comment: I edit the post. In my opinion, we get that the sum is $0$ always, because every even term is minus the following odd term... What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\left|\ln\left(1+\frac{ (-1)^n }{n}\right)\right|\sim_\infty\left|\frac{ (-1)^n }{n}\right|=\frac 1 n$$
so the given series isn't absolutely convergent.

Comment: Is there a proof for this that doesn't use Taylor series?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Note that for even $n$

$$|\log (1+(-1)^n/n)|+|\log(1 + (-1)^{n+1}/(n+1))|=
  2 \bigl\{ \log(n+1) - \log n \bigr\} \geq \frac{1}{n}$$

by the mean value theorem.

Since

$$\sum_{n=2;2}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

your series does not converge absolutely.